# How to change number of machines through a parameter

Tags: anylogic

I am new to anylogic. In the image below there is a process of X-machine, in facility there are 10 such machines with same process. Instead of me creating 10 of those process, is it possible to make a single process and give a parameter for number of machines with same process??

While doing the experiments i will have to be changed the number of machines for validation.

can anyone please help me with it?

[A process in Machine](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTlbl.png)

[agent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CoSqW.png)

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M0jpF.png)

[Main](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TD6zx.png)

Comment: Absolutely, but this is some of the absolute basic capabilities of AnyLogic, tbh. Therefore, I strongly suggest you first do all (!) step-by-step tutorials, they cover this and a ton more stuff, see https://anylogic.help/tutorials/index.html

Comment: (also, for these open-ended "how to" questions, best use the LinkedIn forum. See here for some tips on how to get the most out of the community: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community )

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

you do this:

- create an agent MachineX
- put this process inside the agent
- Create a population of these agents machines
- use a parameter to determine the number of agents in that population

Comment: Thankyou Felipe, Followed the steps but i got an error

"root.fluidSource : out is already connected to in"

Comment: I have added images

Comment: you can't do this.. you can connect the fluid source to only 1 element.. but this is a different question, ask a new question and explain clearly what you need to do... how do you want to distribute the fluid among all the mixing agents? And what do you want to do when the mixer is full, in that case how would the redistribution or logic be.. explain all that in your new question